# Why isn't my ipad saving videos I was emailed?

Tags: ipad, email, video

I have an ipad mini and a freind recently emailed me a video.
When I go into the corner and click save video it then does not appear in any of my photo albums.I have been trying for ages and it is very important at I save this video.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check in the Camera Roll? It isn't going to be in an album if you save it on your iphone from your iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps saving it differently will work for you:

1. Tap and hold on the video thumbnail (in the email message) that you would like to save.
2. Select "Save to Camera Roll".
3. Open Photos.app.
4. Select the "Albums" tab.
5. Select "Camera Roll".
6. The video should be the last one in there.

If this doesn't work, try sending the video to yourself.